# how insert form from project other in visual c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, projects-and-solutions

I have a Project in which there is a form that has several objects (controls) in itself. I want to add this form to another Project in another Solution. How to I can do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good thing to reuse your code :)

You have to make a library project.

1)File => New Project

2)Check Visual project in the tree

then select "Class Library", give it a name "MyFormLib"

3)Then simply copy paste YourForm.cs and YourForm.designer from your app project, to "MyFormLib".

4)Now go to solution explorer, browse to your application project, right click on "references" then "add reference"

5)To finish click on "solution" then choose your library project "MyFormLib"
.

6)You can now use the form from the library project inside your application project.
e.g : new MyFormLib.TheForm()

7) To reuse your form in your second application, redo steps 4 to 6

Answer (score 0):

Just simply open the project where you want to add the existing form:

1. Right click on the Solution Explorer
2. Select "Add" -> "Existing Item..."
3. Browse your other project's folder, and search for the 3 files of your form:

   **yourForm1.cs**, **yourForm1.Designer.cs**, **yourForm1.resx**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to

1. Open the *destination* solution in Visual Studio.
2. On the *Solution Explorer*, right-click the *destination* Solution name and Click on Add > Existing Projects. Identify the project with your *source* Form.
3. Move the form from *source* to *destination* project (The designer and resx files will move with it)
4. Change relevant namespace specifications and then you may remove the old form.